# Spring-Boot content-negotation does not work

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I hope someone can help me.

My problem: I want to create a web backend with spring-boot, which supports REST. For POST-Request, it must accept JSON and XML.

I have implemented a messageConverter with Jackson.
                                           package backend.config;

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
    import                 org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

    import java.util.List;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    /* i have commented this out, bc it does not work for me
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(
        ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            // Simple strategy: only path extension is taken into account
            configurer.
            defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
            mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
            mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
*/

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {

    messageConverters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    super.configureMessageConverters(messageConverters);
}
private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter =
            new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

    XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
    xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

    return xmlConverter;
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
    package backend.controller;


    import backend.entity.User;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import backend.service.UserService;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping(value="/users")
public List<User> getUser(){
    return userService.getAll();
}

@PostMapping(value="/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public void addUser(@RequestBody User user){
    userService.addUser(user);

}
```

If i make a getRequest, everything works fine.
But if i tried a post request, i got this Exception:

```
<linked-hash-map>
    <entry>
        <string>timestamp</string>
        <date>2017-11-03 14:00:14.4 UTC</date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>status</string>
        <int>400</int>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>error</string>
        <string>Bad Request</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>exception</string>
        <string>org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>message</string>
        <string>Failed to convert value of type &apos;backend.entity.User&apos;             to required type &apos;backend.entity.User&apos;</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>path</string>
        <string>/users</string>
    </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

My post request looks like:

```
<backend.entity.User>
    <username>testUserName</username>
    <firstName>testFirstName</firstName>
    <lastName>testLastName</lastName>
</backend.entity.User>
```

And my entity class has these form:

```
package backend.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

@Id
private String username;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;


}
```

My dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Does someone know the reason of my problem?

Thank you guys

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot, then you need to put correct dependency in the pom.xml to activate the converters, you dont need to explicitly configure the converter in WebConfig, for XML, you need to add dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I tried in SpringBoot, with correct dependency and no WebConfig and no explicitly setting converter and it is working fine

Comment: Hello @AmitKBist, thank you for your answer!
I have updated my post, you can see my dependencies right now.
If you make a post request like above, does it work?

Thank you and greetings

Comment: Yes, its working for me but I don't have WebConfig class in my project. As you dont need WebConfig with SpringBoot project. Also if you have declared spring-boot-starter-parent as <parent> node then jackson-* related dependencies

Comment: Can you show me your pom file, i don't get it :(

Comment: Added my pom.xml in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stackoverflow</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

See I have not put any dependency related to Jackson except jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not work for me. :(
I am using a mongodb database with a embedded mongodb server.
Do you mean that could be the reason why i get the error, if i am trying to set a post request in xml?

Thank you :)

Comment: You can see my project on: https://github.com/Nossair93/Stackoverflow
Thank you :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez it does not matter if you are using mongodb, from my pom.xml you need to check that except jackson-xml i have not added any repetitive dependencies.

Comment: I have removed every jackson dependency except:
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
but i am getting the same error like above :(

Comment: Thank you, it works with your dependency. I dont know why it didnt work yesterday